# Return value is not iterable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

```
function useState(initVal){
  const state = initVal 
  const setState = (newVal) => {
    state = newVal
  }

}
const [state,setState] = useState(0)
console.log(state)
TypeError: useState is not a function or its return value is not iterable
    at /home/runner/ViciousSqueakyProfessionals/index.js:8:26
    at Script.runInContext (vm.js:130:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/run_dir/interp.js:209:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
```

I can't seem to figure out why i need the return value to be iterable can someone throw some light over return method in all ;-;

Answer (score 4):

As you are calling the `useState` function and using array destructuring on the return value of the function that is why you need you return the array first in the method itself.

You need to return values as array, Also change state to let for reassigning:

```
function useState(initVal){
  let state = initVal 
  const setState = (newVal) => {
    state = newVal
  }

  return [state, setState];
}
```

You can use these value in either ways:

```
const [state, setState] = useState(0);

// or
const value = useState(0);
value[0] // = state
value[1]() // = setState()
```

The main reason between this and the actual `useState` hook is that change the `state` value won't take component to rerender.

Comment: But I can't figure out why

Comment: What are ou not able to understand?

Comment: That why I have to return values as an array ? cause i am using it like 
```
const [state,setState]=useState('')
``` Later?

Comment: Yes `useState` is just a regular function

Comment: `
function useState(initVal){
  const state = initVal 
  console.log('Ran')
  const setState = (newVal) => {
    console.log('setState ran')
    state = newVal
  }
}` If i do something like this how can i call "setState"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, it looks like react "useState" hook.

"useState" hook has a one arguments and return array(first one is value, second one is function - change value).

```
[Yours]
function useState(initVal){
  const state = initVal 
  const setState = (newVal) => {
    state = newVal
  }

}
const [state,setState] = useState(0) // error - because you are not return any.
console.log(state)
```

```
[Correct]

function useState(initVal){
  const state = initVal 
  const setState = (newVal) => {
    state = newVal
  }

  return [state, setState]

}
const resultOfUseState = useState(0);
console.log(resultOfUseState);
console.log(resultOfUseState[0]);
console.log(resultOfUseState[1]);
```

Maybe, you can understand!

Also, It is possible "resultOfUseState" to const [state, setState] = useState. ( resultOfUseState[0] = state, resultOfUseState[1] = setState )

It calls destructuring.